Gnome Boxes, Linux host, Windows guest, shared folder not appearing
I'm a Linux user.  I use Gnome Boxes to run a Windows VM at income tax time (and for no other reason).  I had this setup running stably since 2022 using an official Microsoft Win10 ISO, my Windows product key, and Spice Guest Tools with WebDAV.
A few months ago, I was forced to do a clean install and upgrade of Ubuntu.  I'm now using 23.10.  The reinstalled Gnome Boxes wouldn't let me boot my old VM.  I don't know why.  It's no great loss, since I always backed up all the critical income tax data from the guest OS.  I didn't need anything else.
I have created a new Windows VM, but I can't get the shared folder back that I use to transfer files between the host and the guest.  I am trying to understand what's wrong.
One thing that bothers me is that I used the same Win10 ISO file to create the new VM that I used in 2022, but the VM installation process forced me to upgrade to Windows 11, whether I wanted it or not.  I don't know that Win11 is actually bad for me, but it's one more variable that I must account for while troubleshooting.
On the guest Win11 OS, I have installed spice-guest-tools-latest and spice-webdavd-x64-latest.  No error messages were observed.
In Gnome Boxes on the host machine, under Devices and Shares, I added my Linux user Public folder to the list of Shared Folders.
When I boot the guest OS, I can't find a folder that I can mount in either This PC or Network.
If I attempt to drag and drop files from the host to the guest, I see a dialog (from Gnome Boxes, I think) with the following text: "Ready to Receive file.  You will find the file in your Downloads directory."  But those files never appear on the guest.
Did I miss a step?  Is there something different about Win11 vs. Win10?  Any advice is appreciated.  Thanks.
